# How to move up/down 1 whole wrapped line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I have a long line wrapped on the screen in Notepad++, how do I move the cursor up/down a whole physical line instead of to the next portion of the wrapped virtual line?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating two macros to go to the start of the physical lines above and below.
e.g.
`Line above` = `Home` `Home` `Up` `Home`
`Line below` = `End` `End` `Right`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible use case that might work for some:

Search in 'Extended' mode for '\n' (newline); and working with the document afterward, use the F3 (Find Next) command to get to the next physical line. This works wonders in wrap mode.